# Extracting properties from stories

Tags: c#, linq, comparative-review

I have a list of items, and a list of actions that extract data from those items. I iterate over the list of items and create a Dictionary for each item that has the data extracted from the item.

I have written a foreach based version to get the data, it works well but is a bit long. I could see that there is a shorter and more concise way to do this with a LINQ expression so I wrote it too.

The LINQ version is a quarter the length of the foreach version and removes a lot of clutter from the code (initializing dictionaries and the foreach loop). In theory that would improve readability but I'm not sure that it actually does since understanding the code becomes a bit more difficult.

The *foreach* version:

```
var allStoriesProperties = new List<Dictionary<string, string>>();
foreach (var story in stories)
{
    var properties = new Dictionary<string, string>();
    foreach (var dataExtractor in dataExtractors)
    {
        var storyProperty = dataExtractor(story);
        properties.Add(storyProperty.Key, storyProperty.Value);
    }
    allStoriesProperties.Add(properties);
}
```

The *LINQ* version:

```
var allStoriesProperties = stories.Select(story => dataExtractors
                                                      .Select(de => de(story))
                                                      .ToDictionary(kvp => kvp.Key, kvp => kvp.Value))
                                                      .ToList();
```

Which way would be preferred?

Comment: If you like terse code, Linq is the way to go, but it has a tendency to hide complexity, which is arguably a bad thing. Basically, people who like Linq will say "use Linq" and people who don't will say use the verbose loop. IMO this is a primarily opinion based question.

Answer (score 1):

I definitely go for the `Linq` version because it is more declarative and at the same time it is shorter and easier to understand but you should use `SelectMany` instead of `Select` because each dataExtractor returns an `IEnumrable` of say `"StoryProperty"` for example.

Besides I would return a `List<StroyProperty>` instead of a `Dictionary<string,string>` if I were you.

Thus the code would be like this :

```
var allStoriesProperties = stories.SelectMany(story => dataExtractors
                                                      .Select(de => de(story))
                                                      .ToList();
```

Of course if you want to return a dictionary you can do it like this :

```
var allStoriesProperties = stories.SelectMany(story => dataExtractors
                                                          .Select(de => de(story))
                                                          .ToDictionary(property=>property.key,property=>property.value);
```

But I can't see why you are returning a list of dictionaries ?

Comment: I am converting this list of dictionaries immediately into another type T using a Func<Dictionary<string,string>,T>. So creating a type for such a short lived object is a bit of a waste. Also, I need to access these properties by name and Dictionary gives me this easily where in a list I'll have to look them up every time. I might use the second way, I'm not sure it it increases or decreases the effrt needed to read the code.

Comment: @Ziv You can always use Linq to get  objects within a specific criteria , for example : `allStoriesProperties.Where(x=>x.name==giveName).ToList();` :)

Comment: Of course I can, but one is O(n), long and unclear and the other is O(1) and has an obvious meaning. Also, I'd probably use `First` or `Single` if I know that the value must exist.

Comment: I have given a deeper look into the code, and this does not do the same thing at all. A SelectMany flattens the sequence, and my code returns a list of dictionaries with each dictionary representing a different story. ie: My code returns a List<Dictionary<string,string>> whereas the given code returns a List<KeyValuePair<string,string>> which does not separate the different stories at the result.

Comment: I knew and that was the whole point :) I was wondering why you should return a list of dictionaries while you can simply return a list of properties ?